How to properly read PWM Duty Cycle using Two Timer (TIM4) Channels?
Library used: Standard Peripheral Library
Hardware:

Test bench that can generate two pwm signals ( A and B )
Cable that connects the test bench to the other board
Other board that should read the signal, delivered by the cable, and detect the pwm duty cycle and frequency (one for A and one for B).

PORT D PIN 12  Tim4 Channel 1
PORT D PIN 13  Tim4 Channel 2
The test bench frequency/PWM generation is working properly so nothing to debug.
The hardware and cable connections are correct (we already triple-checked them )
The problem arises on the other board: The duty cycle calculated seems to point to only one signal, so if I disconnect the cable of the other signal I still manage to calculate the two duty cycles, meanwhile should go to zero
Pin 12 Port D Timer 4 Channel 1 configuration:
void myPWM4_Config_1(tmyPWMInput *me)
{
    RCC_ClocksTypeDef __RCC_CLOCK;

    myPWMInputCtor(me);

    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&__RCC_CLOCK);
    me->clock = __RCC_CLOCK.PCLK1_Frequency * 2; //APB1

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &me->GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    TIM4_IRQHandler_ptf = TIM4_IRQ_PWM;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = 1;
    NVIC_Init(&me->NVIC_InitStructure);

    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 840 - 1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision= TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_1;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;

    TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure);
                                      // Select the TIM8 Input Trigger: TI1FP1
    TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM4, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);
                                          // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
    TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

    TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
                           // Enables TIM8 peripheral Preload register on ARR.
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM4, ENABLE);
    // Configures the TIM8 Update Request Interrupt source (SETS the CR1->URS bit)
    TIM_UpdateRequestConfig(TIM4, TIM_UpdateSource_Regular);

                            // Enable the CC1 and the update Interrupt Request
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1, ENABLE);

    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM4, TIM_FLAG_Update);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}

Pin 13 Port D Tim4 Channel 2 configuration:
void myPWM4_Config_2(tmyPWMInput *me)
{
    RCC_ClocksTypeDef __RCC_CLOCK;

    myPWMInputCtor(me);

    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&__RCC_CLOCK);
    me->clock = __RCC_CLOCK.PCLK1_Frequency * 2; //APB1

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &me->GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    TIM4_IRQHandler_ptf = TIM4_IRQ_PWM;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = 1;
    NVIC_Init(&me->NVIC_InitStructure);

    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 840 - 1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision= TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_2;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;

    TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure);
                                      // Select the TIM8 Input Trigger: TI1FP1
    TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM4, TIM_TS_TI2FP2);
                                          // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
    TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

    TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
                           // Enables TIM8 peripheral Preload register on ARR.
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM4, ENABLE);
    // Configures the TIM8 Update Request Interrupt source (SETS the CR1->URS bit)
    TIM_UpdateRequestConfig(TIM4, TIM_UpdateSource_Regular);

                            // Enable the CC1 and the update Interrupt Request
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2, ENABLE);

    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM4, TIM_FLAG_Update);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}

Capture/Compare Interrupt code:
void TIM4_IRQHandler( void )
{
    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1) != RESET) {
        tmyPWMInput *pPWM4_1 = &myCTRL.myHW.myPortDCfg.myPWM4_1; //PIN12
                          // Clear TIM8 Capture Compare1 interrupt pending bit
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1);

        pPWM4_1->HighPeriod = TIM_GetCapture1(TIM4);       // length of high-portion
        pPWM4_1->FullPeriod = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM4);                 // total period
        myPWMCalc(pPWM4_1); //Calculate the frequency and duty cycle
    }

    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2) != RESET) {
        tmyPWMInput *pPWM4_2 = &myCTRL.myHW.myPortDCfg.myPWM4_2; //PIN13
                          // Clear TIM8 Capture Compare1 interrupt pending bit
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2);

        pPWM4_2->HighPeriod = TIM_GetCapture1(TIM4);       // length of high-portion
        pPWM4_2->FullPeriod = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM4);                 // total period
        myPWMCalc(pPWM4_2); //Calculate the frequency and duty cycle
    }
}

The myPWMCalc function:
void myPWMCalc(tmyPWMInput *me)
{
    uint32_t myClk;
    uint32_t HighPeriod, FullPeriod;

    myClk = (me->clock / (me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler+1));

    // complete period of overflow
    FullPeriod = me->FullPeriod;
    HighPeriod = me->HighPeriod;

    if (FullPeriod < HighPeriod) // lost an overflow
    {
        FullPeriod += me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period;
    }

    me->Frequency = (10 * myClk) / FullPeriod;
    me->DutyCycle = (10000 * HighPeriod) / FullPeriod;

    /* reset overflow */
    me->Overflow = 0;
}

How do I read the two different PWM Signals Duty Cycle I receive from the test bench? ( the frequency get measured correctly)
Output I get: The two duty cycle i calculate are equal because they point to the same frequency signal, so If I disconnect the cable of the other signal I still read two PWM duty cycles.
What I'm supposed to see: duty cycles similar-ish and when i disconnect one signal the duty cycle of the disconnected signal should go to zero.

Just a guess ... STM32 multi channel input capture overcapturing on all channels (interrupts not getting executed)

Which STM32?
The "PWM Input" "feature" as described in STM32 Reference Manual's (RM) TIM chapter requires CH1 and CH2 on one timer to input one signal. It's logical - you want to the hardware to capture two parameters (period and high-time/duty), for that, you need two hardware registers to capture the values into.
That "feature" works by 1. using the "indirect" capture on the other-than-directly-connected channel (capturing on two opposite edges); 2. using Reset mode of the Slave-mode controller of the timer. So, there's no way you can use it for two signals, as one signal uses both channels usable for this feature, and also there is only one slave-mode controller per timer. Read the description of "PWM Input" in the RM.
And, what you do, is, that the second of your configuration functions entirely overrides whatever the first one has set.
Solution is to either A. use two timers; or, B. if the distances between edges are guaranteed to be always far enough, use your connection with two signals on two channels of the same timer, and use captures+interrupts on both edges on both channels, and calculate period/duty for each channel independently from three consecutive captured values.
I'd suggest you to go for A.
PS.

Library used: Serial Peripheral Library

SPL here stands for "Standard Peripheral Library", and be warned that it's been deprecated for perhaps a decade.

Thank you for your input! I'm using STM32F407VG. Could you please tell me which page of the RM talks about TIM requiring CH1 and CH2 to input one signal? So I can read it.

RM0090 chapter 18.3.6 PWM input mode p.608. Two ICx signals are mapped on the same TIx input. read it in context of Figure 159. Capture/compare channel (example: channel 1 input stage), i.e. TIx input is the signal coming from GPIO/input pin, and ICx is the signal which is output from the channel's input circuitry into the input-capture-divider and then subsequently into capturing circuitry itself.

But I was thinking: If I have the interrupt on channel 1 that detects both rising and falling edge and I get the CNT for each edge I can use the three captures to compute the duty cycle, right?

Yes; that's what I wrote in my reply as variant B. Precondition is, that all edges are far enough from each other so that you don't miss an interrupt.

I'm not sure what do you do. stackoverflow is not the best format for this sort of discussion, maybe you want to move it to the STM32 forum.

I've posted another question where I explain in detail what i'm trying to do.
